# Jupyter Notebook overwrites pervious instance of class

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am fairly new to using Jupyter Notebook/Lab and getting some weird behaviour that I am not experiencing with .py file executable. When I create an instance of class defined in the notebook, the most recent instance seems to overwrite all previous instances. Here is my code example to illustrate this:

I create the following test class:

```py
class testclass:

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        testclass.a = a
        testclass.b = b

    def testprint (self):
        print (self.a)
        print (self.b)
```

I create an instance of this class and print its values:

```py
test1 = testclass (1,1)
test1.testprint ()
```

as expected, I get:

```sh
1
1
```

If I create another instance of the same class and print its value:

```py
test2 = testclass (1,2)
test2.testprint ()
```

as expected, I get:

```sh
1
2
```

Now if I reprint the first instance I get the values form the last instance:

```py
test1.testprint ()
```

I get:

```sh
1
2
```

when I expect to get:

```sh
1
1
```

I have tried reinstalling Jupyter Lab in a fresh environment and continue to get the same behavior. Is this a known bug? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in:

```
def __init__(self, a, b):
    testclass.a = a
    testclass.b = b
```

You are using the class name to refer to the specific instance of the class you are initialising. In doing so you are creating (and subsequently mutating) a class attribute rather than an instance attribute. Instead you should use `self`as you have already done correctly in the `testprint` method

```
def __init__(self, a, b):
    self.a = a
    self.b = b
```

By the way, you should read up on overloading the `__str__` and `__repr__` special methods to allow you to print meaningful representations of custom classes without writing new methods like `testprint`.

Comment: Thanks that did it. I also appreciate the tip about __str__ and __reper__